# Multithreading Logic Error (losing data partially at random)

Tags: java, multithreading

I have three methods which run my multithreading in a java program. This program looks through 2^32 - 1 combinations and performs a series of operations on every combination; currently, it spans 700 lines of code and completes in about 6 minutes. I have debugged all the code except for this one error and don't know how to fix it.

This code might be skipping combinations. Specifically, these combinations are lost from my output (partially at random) after transfer from my 'processInputs' method to the class 'ListTask'. Some combinations are 'always' lost while others are 'sometimes' lost.

Could someone please try an help me understand this error? Have I implemented multithreading poorly? If so, how can I fix it?

---

Strangely, when I search within finalize() for a combination that is always lost in my output, the combination is suddenly processed by ListTask and outputs successfully (i.e., it does not output unless I confirm it's presence in finalize() first).

I search for a specific combination from finalize() in my while loop via :

```
for (List<int[]> jobs : ranTime) {
    for (int[] combin : jobs) {
        if (Arrays.equals(combin, schedule) == true) {
            System.out.println("true");
        }
    }
}
```

where schedule is the array combination I'm searching for. An example combination (plus other pending data with 999 as a divider) is:

```
int[] schedule = {0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,999,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
```

---

Method "finalize()" declares my ExecutorService: (processes all 2^32 - 1 combinations)

```
public static void finalize(List<List<Integer>> matTan, boolean transposed, int minimum, String[] args, int[] colKeep) {
    final int A = matTan.size();
    final int B = matTan.get(0).size();
    boolean judge = true;

    if (minimum > A && transposed == false || minimum > B && transposed == true) {
        System.out.print("\nMinimum too high\n\n");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    ValMax.valMax = 460;  //userinput
    int[] rows  = new int[2 + A + B];
    List<int[]> combination = new ArrayList<int[]>(100);

    int threads = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
    ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threads);

    List<List<int[]>> ranTime = new ArrayList<List<int[]>>(threads);
    for (int x = 0; x < threads; x++) {
        List<int[]> jobs = new ArrayList<int[]>(90);
        ranTime.add(jobs);
    }

    if (transposed == false) {
        for (int x = 1; x <= minimum; x++) {
            rows[x] = 1;
        }
    } else {
        rows[1] = 1;
    }
    rows[A + 1] = 999;

    int y = 0, z = 0;
    System.out.println(threads + "\n");
    while (rows[A + 1] == 999) {
        y++;
        int[] copy = Arrays.copyOf(rows, rows.length);


        if (y == 91) {
            z++;
            y = 1;
            if (z < threads) {
                ranTime.get(z).clear();
            }
        }

        if (z == threads) {
            processInputs(ranTime, combination, matTan, minimum, transposed, service);
            z = 0;
            ranTime.get(0).clear();
            ranTime.get(0).add(copy);
        } else {
            ranTime.get(z).add(copy);
        }

        nextComb(A, rows);
    }

    if (ranTime.get(0).size() > 0) {
        for (int x = 0; x < threads; x++) {
            if (judge == false) {
                ranTime.remove(x);
                threads--;
                x--;
            }

            if (ranTime.get(x).size() != 90 && judge == true) {
            judge = false;
            }
        }

        processInputs(ranTime, combination, matTan, minimum, transposed, service);
    }

    service.shutdown();

    try {
        service.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    } catch (InterruptedException e6) {
        System.out.print("Termination Error!");
    }

    System.out.print("\n");
    List<int[]> combinationNew = developed(matTan, combination, transposed, colKeep);
    ProcessFiles.writeEverything(combinationNew, args, transposed);
}
```

Method "ProcessInputs()" submits 4 jobs (since I have 4 cores) and submits them to ExecutorService: (processes all 2^32 - 1 combinations)

```
private static void processInputs(List<List<int[]>> ranTime, List<int[]> combination, List<List<Integer>> matTan, int minimum, boolean transposed, ExecutorService service) {
    for (List<int[]> jobs : ranTime) {
        StringTask analysis = new StringTask(jobs, combination, matTan, minimum, transposed);
        service.submit(analysis);
    }
}
```

Class "ListTask" with method "call()" performs a series of operations on each combination and saves the result if significant for future I/O: (I'm new to multithreading and don't know how to check how many combinations are processed. However, I KNOW my error begins here since the other methods before it process all combinations).

```
class ListTask implements Callable<Void> {
    private List<List<Integer>> matTan;
    private List<int[]> combination;
    private List<int[]> jobs;
    private boolean transposed;
    private int minimum;

    ListTask(List<int[]> a, List<int[]> b, List<List<Integer>> c, int d, boolean e) {
        this.combination = b;
        this.minimum = d;
        this.transposed = e;
        this.matTan = c;
        this.jobs = a;
    }

    public Void call() {
        for (int[] e : jobs) {
            int temp = Multi.reduct2(e, matTan, minimum, transposed);
            if (temp >= ValMax.valMax) { //ValMax.valMax //userinput
                e[0] = temp;
                combination.add(e);
                System.out.print(temp + " ");
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I may be missing something, but I don't see any synchronisation logic?

Comment: Could you please explain a bit further? This is my first attempt at multithreading with no formal education so if it's important I might be missing it. However, the operations performed on each combination is completely independent of all other combinations and the order at which they are added to combination does not matter.

Comment: You first need to think in multithreading way. Identify what mutable objects are shared among your threads. Then, you need to synchronize any read/write to these objects...so no two threads change the object at the same time. Also, no thread changes a value that another thread is reading at the same time

Comment: Thank you. I will research this and see if it fixes my problem. In the meantime, if either of you could provide a good source for synchronisation that I might overlook I would appreciate it! (looking at the java docs tutorials now)